# Deploying monstache in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, yaml

I have deployed monstache with docker-compose as follows:

```
  blascal_tasks_monstache:
    image: rwynn/monstache:6.7.6
    container_name: dev_monstache
    working_dir: /monstache
    command: -f ./config.toml
    volumes:
      - ./monstache/dev:/monstache/
    ports:
      - "5556:8080"
    restart: always
```

It works fine, but trying to deploy it in kubernetes i get an error:

```
ERROR 2021/10/06 20:07:56 open ./config.toml: no such file or directory
```

here is my spec:

```
   spec:
         containers:
           - args:
               - -f
               - ./config.toml
             image: rwynn/monstache:6.7.6
             name: dev-monstache
             ports:
               - containerPort: 8080
             resources: {}
             volumeMounts:
               - mountPath: /monstache/dev
                 name: monstache-claim
             workingDir: /monstache
```

How do i specify the file?

Comment: The developer-oriented Docker approach of running an unmodified base image and then bind-mounting your code into it doesn't work well in Kubernetes; the cluster won't usually have access to your local filesystem, and replicating the two Compose `volumes:` lines can double or triple the total size of the Kubernetes YAML.  Can you build your application code into an image instead of trying to mount it into the container?

Comment: @david-maze Kindly advice here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475221/exposing-several-socket-io-paths-in-ingress

Answer (score 0):

`./config.toml: no such file or directory`

To make the config available to your pod, first create a ConfigMap resource with the config file:

`kubectl create configmap monstache-claim --from-file=config.toml`

Then mount the config in your pod spec:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: monstache-claim
    configMap:
      name: monstache-claim
  containers:
  - args:
  ...
```

You will be able to access /monstache/dev/config.toml in the pod.